# Why if an angular function clicks the button the values I want to change don't do it but if I manually press the button it does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

the problem here is that I have a form that gets his values form an angular function. I have one button that change the values for the inputs tags and I have a submit button that send those values. So when I press that last button It work fine. But I want that the first button not only changes the form's values also click the submit button.
 So here is the function that changes the form's values.

```
 todoList.remove = function(aborrar) {
  if (aborrar.id != undefined || aborrar.id != null) {
    todoList.elaborrar = aborrar.id;
    console.log("si tiene id y es "+aborrar.id);
    todoList.elnoquerido = '/api/users/remove_tags/<%=user.id%>';
    console.log(todoList.elnoquerido);
    $('#elimina').trigger("click"); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM

  };
  angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function(todo,i) {
    if (aborrar.title==todo.title) {
        todoList.todos.splice(i, 1);
    };
  });
};
```

and the html

```
<form name='myform2' method="POST" class="" novalidate action="{{todoList.elnoquerido}}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>">
    <input name="aborrars" type="hidden" value="{{todoList.elaborrar}}">
    <input id="elimina" class="btn btn-medium btn-primary elimina" type="submit"  value="Eliminar">
  </form>
```

I think this may is happen because some async thing? I've also try with this...

```
document.getElementById("elimina").click();
```

and this

```
$('#elimina').click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/t34z7/212/)

```
angular.element('#elimina').triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: Explain WHY this would work.

Comment: also don't work, or this `angular.element('#elimina').trigger('click');`

Comment: you have to use `triggerHandler` with `$timeout` you can read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: I am making fiddle for you

Comment: added working fiddle in my answer, please go through it

Comment: Thank you a lot @DevidasKadam it works with `$('#elimina').click();`  and because I'm so beginner with javascript and angular I've just forgot the `$timeout` on the controller haha  `angular.module('angular', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {`